# number of (identical) items sold together

Tags: single-word-requests

Say a shop sells eggs only in packs of 12 or paper clips only in packs of 100.  How do you refer to that number in general?

I thought `sales unit` or `selling unit` might be the right terms, but those seem to refer to the shop/outlet/person selling an item.

Comment: Package quantity?

Comment: Minimum saleable units.

Comment: @deadrat : would you say "package quantity" works if items aren't physically packaged or sold in bags for example?

Comment: The only place I've seen items sold loose but not by-the-each is at Costco, where, for example, loaves of bread are priced by the pair, mix or match—you grab a bag and "package" your pair of loaves. I don't think they can ring up the sale if you don't use the bag—it has the barcode on it.  Even if you didn't package them, though, it's still a _package deal_.   As for deals such as "corn 5 ears for $1", you are not obligated to buy that many.

Comment: @JohannesBauer I was misled by the word "pack."  No, "package quantify" requires a package.

Comment: The general term is "lot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lot size** or **lot quantity**:

a measure or quantity increment acceptable to, or specified by, the party offering to buy or sell

Source: [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/lot-size.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the word in your question - a *pack* or *package*. A sales rep would say e.g. "Do you want a pack or are you buying individually"? or "I can give you a package discount, but I can't do that price if I have to break the pack".

Comment: My feeling is that you can't refer directly to a number as a 'pack.'  Or would you say something like "the pack for light bulbs is six, but the pack for toilet paper rolls is eight?"

Comment: @JohannesBauer, yes, that's what I'd say (almost): e.g. "Our toilet rolls are sold in packs of 4, 8 or 16"; "I'd like you to get me a pack of 6 light bulbs please"; and there is the well-known "6-pack" of beer.

Answer (score 1):

**quantity per**

> The number of individual units of a given SKU number that are required
>   to make up a larger unit. For example, a given item might have a
>   quantity per box of 10 individual units for sales purposes.

From: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/quantity-per.html#ixzz3jskzJd3N

Comment: Good term (albeit not pretty, linguistically).  Accepting `lot size` because it seems more specifically applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a

**minimum purchase quantity**

This conveys what I think you meant, regardless whether the product is in one package, or several, or none—it even works for *non-countable* product (for instance, a minimum one-pound purchase of bulk flour) or for a *not-counted* product (e.g., a quarter-pound of jellybeans)